# ArangoDB - Get results returned from Traverser steps

Tags: javascript, arangodb, aql, foxx

Is it possible to get back results from a Traverser step in ArangoDB / Foxx service?

I'm looking to implement ohmic resistance calculations on a power grid graph.
Herein I traverse BFS (breadth-first) down the graphs' edges to it's leafs. - No problem.
Using Filters, Expanders and Visitors is just fine!

My interest is to perform `1/x` calculations for each line at a branching node / step to solve parallel resistance when coming "back to the root / top" of the graph.

So, my question is:
"Is it possible to get a return value from each step?" - If yes where can I specify calculate the return value?

Thanks for any hints!

*UPDATE 2017-12-21: Further explanation*

Here's an image of a Demo Graph of my case: [Image of the Demo Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhJZw.png)
Explanation of the image:
* The "black" values are the raw ohmic values for the calculation (e.g. weight of the edge in a weighted graph).
* The "red" values are calculated ohmic values (subresults) for each step.

CSV Data of the Graph:

- Nodes:

```
"_key","stationId","voltage","voltageKey","pathId","elementId","type","typeKey","name","status","oStatus","isSource","sourceColor","isStrandSource","isStrandEnd","strandSourceColor"
"NE-2_J_1","2","20","J","","1","conn","","root","1","1","","","","",""
"NE-2_J_2","2","20","J","","2","conn","","Abzweig 1","1","1","","","","",""
"NE-2_J_3","2","20","J","","3","conn","","Abzweig 2","1","1","","","","",""
"NE-2_J_4","2","20","J","","4","conn","","Abzweig 3","1","1","","","","",""
"NE-2_J_5","2","21","J","","5","conn","","Abzweig 4","1","1","","","","",""
"NE-2_J_6","2","22","J","","6","conn","","Abzweig 5","1","1","","","","",""
"NE-2_J_7","2","23","J","","7","conn","","Abzweig 6","1","1","","","","",""
"NE-2_J_8","2","24","J","","8","conn","","Abzweig 7","1","1","","","","",""
```

- Edges:

```
"_key","_from","_to","elementId","type","typeKey","voltage","voltageKey","name",
"status","oStatus","xOhm"
"NE-J19","NE-2_J_1","NE-2_J_2","19","solid","","20","J","","1","1","1"
"NE-J20","NE-2_J_2","NE-2_J_3","20","solid","","20","J","","1","1","2"
"NE-J21","NE-2_J_2","NE-2_J_4","21","solid","","20","J","","1","1","3"
"NE-J22","NE-2_J_3","NE-2_J_5","22","solid","","20","J","","1","1","4"
"NE-J23","NE-2_J_3","NE-2_J_6","23","solid","","20","J","","1","1","5"
"NE-J24","NE-2_J_4","NE-2_J_7","24","solid","","20","J","","1","1","6"
"NE-J25","NE-2_J_4","NE-2_J_8","25","solid","","20","J","","1","1","7"
```

Explanation of the calculation:

- The calculation is performed "bottom up" so my intention was to handle the math after the traverser "returns" the result from the underlying graph.
- Step 1: Calculate the resulting (parallel) resistance of the "bottom left" branch ("NE-2_J_5" AND "NE-2_J6") at "NE-2_J_3":

  - The math for this is `1 / ( 1/4 Ohm + 1/5 Ohm ) = 2,22 Ohm`
- Step 2: Calculate the resulting (parallel) resistance of the "bottom right" branch ("NE-2_J_7" AND "NE-2_J_8") at "NE-2_J_4":

  - The math for this is `1 / ( 1/6 Ohm + 1/7 Ohm ) = 3,23 Ohm`
- Step 3: Calculate the resulting (inline) resistance of the "bottom left" branch ("NE-2_J_3 raw" value AND "NE-2_J_3 calculated") before calculating Step 5:

  - The math for this is `2 Ohm + 2,22 Ohm = 4,22 Ohm`
- Step 4: Calculate the resulting (inline) resistance of the "bottom right" branch ("NE-2_J_4 raw" value AND "NE-2_J_4 calculated") before calculating Step 5:

  - The math for this is `3 Ohm + 3,23 Ohm = 6,23 Ohm`
- Step 5: Calculate the resulting (parallel) resistance of the "center" branch (Step 3 AND Step 4) at "NE-2_J_2":

  - The math for this is `1 / ( 1/4,22 Ohm + 1/6,23 Ohm ) = 2,52 Ohm`
- Step 6: Calculate the resulting (inline) resistance of the "center" branch ("NE-2_J_2 raw" value AND "NE-2_J_2 calculated") for the final result at "NE-2_J_1":

  - The math for this is `1 Ohm + 2,52 Ohm = 3,52 Ohm`

Comment: So if your traversal goes 1..n in depth, you basically want to do something for depth 1..2, 2..3, 3..4 etc.? Can you add a breakdown of the steps you want to take, indicating the position in graph traversal and the intermediate values? Also, would AQL traversal be possible (you seem to be using JS traversal)?

Comment: thanks @codemanx - I extended the description and hope to describe things better for further / deeper understanding.